# Python AIOHTTP gets slow after a number of requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, request, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using aiohttp library in Python to make async requests. I use the following code:

```python
async def get_response(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        response_json = await resp.json()
        return response_json


async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    for round in num_rounds:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(1000):
            url = "some_url[i]"
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_response(session, url)))

        output = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

So for `num_rounds` I am doing pretty the same stuff: making 1000 async requests.

**Problem**: after 10-15 rounds aiohttp gets SUPER slow. For example rounds 1,2,3,... were completed in 10-15 seconds per round, when rounds after 15th take more than 200 seconds per round... What could be the reason of this behavior and what could be the fixes?

I was trying several things:

1. It is not the network issue, since I was trying to run this code within different networks and the behavior is the same everywhere.
2. It is not likely to be the server issue (i.e., slow down from the server side), because if I will hard stop the code and immediately run it again the timings will be the same (fast at the beginning, super slow further)
3. I tried to move `async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:` line inside the `for round in num_rounds:` loop, but surprisingly the behavior is the same (?!)

Would appreciate any help on how to fix this slowdowns...

Comment: I've tried your code on `https://www.wikipedia.org` and each round completed in ~1 second (for each round - I've tried 100). So issue must be somewhere else. Try to use [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) your code and see where you spend most of time.

Comment: Thanks @AndrejKesely for the suggestion. I am using binance.com to request some data, so might it be that the server is slowing down my requests after the certain period? Could the problem be in the task scheduler of Asyncio or in aiohttp? Because it looks like that wikipedia queries were quite light and I am requesting lots of data..

Comment: Do you store the data in memory? Could be that memory is full and you begin to swap(?) I suggest to profile your code.

Comment: Hm @AndrejKesely, might be indeed (as I am storing everything in RAM now), thank you for this point. Yes, I will try to profile the code now.

Comment: given your description, you are likely being throttled on the target server, due to excessive requests.

Comment: I see you think it is not the server, but then trying adding some pause between rounds - like a couple seconds to simulate "break and restart"- the way your code is, it will send 1000 requests, and then another 1000 without any interval: if there is some  throtling it is up to you to map-it-out if there is no support on the server you could ask (like, if this is a paid-for service)